# Add new property to existing array of object from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't know how to write the title properly, pardon me on that.

Basically I have a list of array of object that's coming from a place, I need to map them together. How how with my code below I can't make it.

```js
const person = [
  {name:'hello',id:1},
  {name:'javascript',id:2},
  {name:'world',id:3}
];

const selected = [2,3];


const normalized = person.map((obj,i) => obj.id === selected[i] ? Object.assign({}, obj, {checked:true}) : obj);

console.log(normalized)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q9g0kazx/1/

I need to add an extra property base on the selected array. Why above code doesn't work?

Comment: What is the exact expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, just iterate through the array using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example) and add the property if needed.

```js
const person = [
   {name: 'hello', id: 1},
   {name: 'javascript',id: 2},
   {name: 'world',id: 3}
];

const selected = [2,3];

person.forEach(p => {
  if (selected.includes(p.id)) {
    p.checked = true;
  }
});

console.log(person);
```

Or you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
const person = [
   {name: 'hello', id: 1},
   {name: 'javascript',id: 2},
   {name: 'world',id: 3}
];

const selected = [2,3];

person.map(p => {
  if (selected.includes(p.id)) {
    p.checked = true;
  }
  return p;
});

console.log(person);
```

**Notice that you have to `return` the object (person in our case)**

Comment: Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control It's actually, check if the index in `selected`, just like `selected.indexOf(p.id) > -1`

Comment: normally I will use indexOf, it's more common, what's the advantage of using includes than indexOf?

Comment: I personally prefer a function that returns the type I expected e.g boolean. `indexOf` for check if exist seems like hack for me. Thankfully, es6 allowed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Check if the the id in the array is present in the `selected` array by:

```
selected.includes(obj.id)
```

So, includes returns `true` if the `obj.id` was present in the  `selected` array. If present(yes) then your `Object.assign`part of code executes.

The reason your code was not working was because your `person` array and `selected` array don't have same number of elements(count) and perhaps not in the order as well.
So `person[0]` id which is 1 doesn't match with `selected[0]` id which 2 and so on.

```js
const person = [{
    name: 'hello',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'javascript',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'world',
    id: 3
  }
];

const selected = [2, 3];

const normalized = person.map((obj, i) => selected.includes(obj.id) ? Object.assign({}, obj, {
  checked: true
}) : obj);

console.log(normalized);
```